# object > array > forEach object > array > push variable does not save after closing out of forEach loop

Tags: javascript, express

I'm thinking it has something to do with the way javascript handles parent/child mutating... but I"m not sure.

The code:

```
router.get('/:id/articles', authenticate, async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    let user = await db.getUserIdName(req.params.id);

    if (user) {
      articles = await db.getUserArticles(req.params.id);
      user.articles = articles;

      // select categories.id from `articles_categories_relationship` join `categories` on `articles_categories_relationship`.`article_id` = `categories`.`id` where `articles_categories_relationship`.`category_id` = '1'

      let finalUser = Object.assign({}, user);

      user.articles.forEach(async (article, index) => {
        finalUser.articles[index].categories = [];
        const newCategories = await dbArticles.getCategoriesByArticleId(
          article.id
        );

        newCategories.forEach(async category => {
          await finalUser.articles[index].categories.push(category.id);
        });
        console.log(newCategories);
        console.log(finalUser.articles[index].categories);
      });
      console.log(finalUser);
      // console.log(user.articles[0]);

      res.status(200).json(finalUser);
    } else {
      next({ code: 400 });
    }
  } catch (err) {
    next(err);
  }
});
```

Here is what the `console.log()`'s output is...
Note: see `categories`

```
{ id: 1,
  display_name: 'RandomBlogger',
  articles:
   [ { id: 1,
       user_id: 1,
       cover_page: 'https://coverpage1.com/',
       title: 'Hello World',
       link: 'https://helloworld.com/',
       categories: [] },
     { id: 2,
       user_id: 1,
       cover_page: 'https://i.imgur.com/zbg9mtf.png',
       title: 'Lambda Strikes Down Students With New Build Week',
       link: '',
       categories: [] },
     { id: 3,
       user_id: 1,
       cover_page: '',
       title: 'Deadlines?-?Bad reason for bad code.',
       link: 'https://medium.com/mindorks/deadlines-bad-reason-for-bad-code-d3d5fe22f3ff',
       categories: [] } ] }
::1 - GET /users/1/articles HTTP/1.1 200 526 - 7.632 ms
[ { id: 1 }, { id: 3 } ]
[ 1, 3 ]
[ { id: 2 } ]
[ 2 ]
[ { id: 1 } ]
[ 1 ]
```

Here is what I expect from the `console.log()`'s output...
Note: see `categories`

```
{ id: 1,
  display_name: 'RandomBlogger',
  articles:
   [ { id: 1,
       user_id: 1,
       cover_page: 'https://coverpage1.com/',
       title: 'Hello World',
       link: 'https://helloworld.com/',
       categories: [ 1, 3 ] },
     { id: 2,
       user_id: 1,
       cover_page: 'https://i.imgur.com/zbg9mtf.png',
       title: 'Lambda Strikes Down Students With New Build Week',
       link: '',
       categories: [ 2 ] },
     { id: 3,
       user_id: 1,
       cover_page: '',
       title: 'Deadlines?-?Bad reason for bad code.',
       link: 'https://medium.com/mindorks/deadlines-bad-reason-for-bad-code-d3d5fe22f3ff',
       categories: [ 1 ] } ] }
::1 - GET /users/1/articles HTTP/1.1 200 526 - 7.632 ms
[ { id: 1 }, { id: 3 } ]
[ 1, 3 ]
[ { id: 2 } ]
[ 2 ]
[ { id: 1 } ]
[ 1 ]
```

If anyone could explain to me why these changes are not being saved after it exits the parent `forEach` loop, I would be very grateful

Comment: Please don't abbreviate JavaScript as "Java" ...

Comment: The code *after* the `forEach` does run *before* the code *inside the `forEach` behind the first `await`* runs, so you actually want to properly wait for the things forEach is doing before continuing, see dupe.

Comment: made the change from "java" to "javascript" (sorry about that), and yeah I just realized the console log is logging out of order, so I added two `await` in front of both `forEach` loops, but that didn't change anything

Comment: please *read the dupe* ...

Comment: I did, so my first forEach loop was already doing that, I added the 2nd async/wait to the 2nd forEach loop. Am I doing that correctly? (I edited the question)... because this is still not working.

Comment: Seriously. Read the dupe! `If you want to read the files in sequence, you cannot use forEach indeed` ...

Comment: okay thanks, I guess i'll change it to a for.

Comment: Just want to say thanks again for help. Making the change worked... this question is indeed a duplicate... but I will post the solution code anyway